# Issue with programmatic route navigation using angular 2 RC router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am using the RC router as of rc1 and I have two routes defined as follows:

```
@Routes([
    {path: '/', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '/signin', component: SigninComponent},
    {path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
])
```

And I am trying to navigate to `'/signin'` upon sign out as follows:

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: '[signout]',
    templateUrl: 'app/session/session.signout.component.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES],
    pipes: [TranslatePipe]
})
export class SignoutComponent {

    constructor(private router:Router,
                private sessionService:SessionService) {
    }

    signout() {
        this.sessionService.signout();
        //FIXME: does not navigate to '/signin'
        this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
    }

}
```

However, when I sign out, the route/url displayed in the browser is the root url (`/`) and not the signin url...

What I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@Routes([
    {path: '/', component: HomeComponent},
    {path: '/signin', component: SigninComponent},
    {path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
])
```

to

```
@Routes([
    {path: '/signin', component: SigninComponent},
    {path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
    {path: '/', component: HomeComponent},
])
```

That's a known issue and should be fixed with one of the next releases.

Comment: No luck with the provided solution. Can you please point me to the relevant issue in github?

Comment: This is mentioned at several places. One is https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8420

Comment: Thanks. I don't get any exception in the console. It might be a different bug. I'll wait till the new RC come out and see.